# Why does using ASP.NET OutputCache keep returning a 200 OK, not a 304 Not Modified?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, outputcache, cache-control, iis-7.5

i have a simple aspx page. Here's the top of it:-

```
<%@ Page 
    Language="C#" 
    AutoEventWireup="true" 
    CodeFile="Foo.aspx.cs" 
    Inherits="Foo" %>
<%@ OutputCache Duration="3600" VaryByParam="none" Location="Any" %>
```

Now, every time I hit the page in FireFox (either hit F5 or hit enter in the url bar) I keep getting a 200 OK response. Here's a sample reply from FireBug :-

Request Headers:-

```
GET /sitemap.xml HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost.foo.com.au
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-GB; rv:1.9.2) 
            Gecko/20100115 Firefox/3.6
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-au,en-gb;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: <snipped>
If-Modified-Since: Tue, 01 Jun 2010 07:35:17 GMT
If-None-Match: ""
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

Response Headers:-

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: public
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Expires: Tue, 01 Jun 2010 08:35:17 GMT
Last-Modified: Tue, 01 Jun 2010 07:35:17 GMT
Etag: ""
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: UrlRewriter.NET 2.0.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Date: Tue, 01 Jun 2010 07:35:20 GMT
Content-Length: 775
```

Firebug Cache tab:-

```
Last Modified   Tue Jun 01 2010 17:35:20 GMT+1000 (AUS Eastern Standard Time)
Last Fetched    Tue Jun 01 2010 17:35:20 GMT+1000 (AUS Eastern Standard Time)
Expires Tue Jun 01 2010 18:35:17 GMT+1000 (AUS Eastern Standard Time)
Data Size   775
Fetch Count 105
Device  disk
```

Now, if i try it in Fiddler using the Request Builder (and no extra data) I also keep getting the same 200 OK reply.

Request Headers:-

```
GET http://localhost.foo.com.au/sitemap.xml HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: foo.com.au
```

Response Headers:-

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: public
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Expires: Tue, 01 Jun 2010 07:58:00 GMT
Last-Modified: Tue, 01 Jun 2010 06:58:00 GMT
ETag: ""
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: UrlRewriter.NET 2.0.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Date: Tue, 01 Jun 2010 06:59:16 GMT
Content-Length: 775
```

It looks like it's asking to cache it but it's not :(

Server is a localhost IIS7.5 on Win7. (as listed in the Response data).

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It's could happen cause of URL Rewriting. Try to access page via ~.aspx path, if it's ok, so the reason is urlRewriter module.

Comment: @Pure.Krome ever found an explanation/solution for this ?

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli nope. never got an aswer for this.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should set `VaryByParam=""` instead `"none"` in order to get the `expected 304` (not modified when the user use enter key in url bar).

Using `"" Vary HttpHeader` is **not** sent to the server as part of the request headers.

Using `"None" Vary HttpHeader` **is** sent to the server as part of the request headers.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the website from a different machine to ensure that this isn't behaviour of localhost calls.

Comment: Still getting the same thing. all 200's.